# How to add collisions to player movements? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-controls, collision

I have a code here which causes the player to move in the direction of the camera. The movements work but the player goes through walls and I've tried adding a box collider to the p[layer but that didn't work. I tried adding a rigid body but it limited my movement to the x and z axis but my game is set underwater and I need the player to be able to swim up if they are facing up as well.

Please can someone help me.

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class Movement1 : MonoBehaviour {

```
/* 
wasd : basic movement
shift : Makes camera accelerate */
 
public float sensX;
public float sensY;
public Transform orientation;

float xRotation;
float yRotation;
float mainSpeed = 5.0f; //regular speed
float shiftAdd = 8.0f; //multiplied by how long shift is held.  Running
float maxShift = 12.0f; //Maximum speed when holdin gshift
float camSens = 0.25f; //How sensitive the mouse is
private Vector3 lastMouse = new Vector3(255, 255, 255); //sets mouse near the middle
private float totalRun= 1.0f;

private void Start()
    {
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

void Update () {
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensX;
  float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensY;

  yRotation += mouseX;
  xRotation -= mouseY;
  xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

  transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
  orientation.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);
   
    //Keyboard commands
    float f = 0.0f;
    Vector3 p = GetBaseInput();
    if (p.sqrMagnitude > 0){ // only move while a direction key is pressed
      if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftShift)){
          totalRun += Time.deltaTime;
          p  = p * totalRun * shiftAdd;
          p.x = Mathf.Clamp(p.x, -maxShift, maxShift);
          p.y = Mathf.Clamp(p.y, -maxShift, maxShift);
          p.z = Mathf.Clamp(p.z, -maxShift, maxShift);
      } else {
          totalRun = Mathf.Clamp(totalRun * 0.5f, 1f, 1000f);
          p = p * mainSpeed;
      }
            
      p = p * Time.deltaTime;
      Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){ //If player wants to move on X and Z axis only
          transform.Translate(p);
          newPosition.x = transform.position.x;
          newPosition.z = transform.position.z;
          transform.position = newPosition;
      } else {
          transform.Translate(p);
      }
    }
}

private Vector3 GetBaseInput() { //returns the basic values, if it's 0 than it's not active.
    Vector3 p_Velocity = new Vector3();
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)){
        p_Velocity += new Vector3(0, 0 , 1);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)){
        p_Velocity += new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)){
        p_Velocity += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)){
        p_Velocity += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    }
    return p_Velocity;
}
```

}

Edit:
I have a new script written. The collision works but the player can't move in the way axis.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewMovement : MonoBehaviour
```

{

[Header("Movement")]
public float moveSpeed;

```
    public Transform orientation;

float horizontalInput;
float verticalInput;

Vector3 moveDirection;

Rigidbody rb;

// Start is called before the first frame update
private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
rb.freezeRotation = true;
    
}
private void MyInput()
{
horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
}

private void MovePlayer()
{

moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput;

rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 8f, ForceMode.Force);
}
// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    MyInput();
SpeedControl();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
MovePlayer();
}

private void SpeedControl()
{
Vector3 flatVel = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y, rb.velocity.z);

if(flatVel.magnitude > moveSpeed)
{
    Vector3 limitedVel = flatVel.normalized * moveSpeed;
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(limitedVel.x, rb.velocity.y, limitedVel.z);
}
}
```

}

Code for Camera Movement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewCamMovement : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
    public float sensX;
    public float sensY;
    public Transform orientation;
    float xRotation;
float yRotation;

private void Start()
    {
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensX;
float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensY;

yRotation += mouseX;
xRotation -= mouseY;
xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
orientation.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);
    
}
```

}
Here is a video that show cases the movement that I want from the old script, the only issue with it is that it doesn't detect collisions.
https://youtu.be/Sa3Xo9IH47Y

Comment: You arent moving using physics.

Comment: @BugFinder what would I have to change to make it use physics?

Comment: Dont set the transform position. You need to use the rigidbody. Various methods are available have a read up on what suits best.

Comment: I've created a script using rigid body, the collisions work but I have a problem with the movements. the player moves in the x and z direction but won't move up nor down when the camera faces the upwards or downwards direction. I'm struggling to find anything online on how to make the player move in an upwards or downwards direction.

Comment: Does the wall you trying to collide has a collider as well? You need have collider in your player and in each object you intend to collide (walls, floor, props) to detect collsions

Comment: Is this a 3d game? Third person camera?

Comment: @DouglasFerreira Yes both the player and the camera have a collider. It's a 3D game with a first person camera

Comment: Having both colliders, and a rigidbody the collisions are computed automatically, except when your using transform.Translate or transform.position, those calls will override the physics calcualtion... only move the playable object through rigidbody...

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the transform.position and transform.translate into the Rigid body way. I've tried it before and there was either an error that I couldn't fix or the movements just didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this script with the help of a youtuber which does exactly what I want and has collisions as well.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwimScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public float moveX;
public float moveY;
public float moveZ;
public float speed = 1;

Transform t;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
t = this.transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move();
}
void Move()
{
moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
moveY = Input.GetAxis("Up+Down");
moveZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

t.Translate(new Vector3(moveX, 0, moveZ) * Time.deltaTime * speed);
t.Translate(new Vector3(0, moveY, 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed, Space.World);
 }
```

}

I'm new to C# so if someone wants to add more details to explain how and why this works, please do.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the concept of the rigidBody may not be clear for you. When you add a rigidBody component to your object it means that now it is affected by gravity and other unity physics mechanics, like drag and forces.

So, if you are using rigidBody, is probably not a good idea to change the player position with `transform.position += ...`,you should use `rigiBody.AddForce()`, so the unity physics engine will do the calculations of the movement for you.

Other option, that might be more suitable to your case is to disable gravity in your rigidbody, setting the paramenter gravity scale to 0. This way you can move the rigidbody freely in all axis using `transform.position += ...`. You are probably struggling because the gravity is pushing your rigidbody down while you try to change it Y position.

Comment: I've created a new script that uses the Rigid body but the player is locked to moving only on the x and z axis and I need it to move on Y.

Comment: Did you set the gravity scale on the rigidbody component to 0?

Comment: Gravity is turned off

Comment: Can you show the new script that you created and the configuration of your rigidbody?  In your previous code you were not moving in the Y axis

Comment: This is part of the new code I'm using. 

'private void MyInput()
    {
 horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
 verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    private void MovePlayer()
    {

 moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput;

 rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 8f, ForceMode.Force);'

I can't add more due to the character limit.

Comment: Please edit your original post, adding all the infos

Comment: The post has been edited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253365/discussion-between-renan-ruan-and-dawid).